# How do I create an `NSArray` out of a managed (C#) array of, say, `int`s?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nsarray

I have a managed array of `int`s, let's call it `int[] intArray`, and I'm trying to create an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s from it. What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given:

```
int[] intArray = {1,2,3};
```

You can do:

```
NSArray nsArray = NSArray.FromObjects(intArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is the simplest way if the (C#) array values are known at time you create the `NSArray` instance.

An alternative, if you need to modify (e.g. add more or remove items) the array after the creation, is to create an `NSMutableArray` and call its `Add` method to add your own values.

Since you're using `int` you'll need to call `NSObject.FromObject` on each integer you have.

```
int[] intArray = {1,2,3};
var nsArray = new NSMutableArray (3);
foreach (int i in intArray)
   nsArray.Add (NSObject.FromObject (i));
```

Comment: I don't think you can iterate an NSArray like that?